# Issue on Setting Up Highchats.js Index of Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/87m56/) and let me know how I can get rid of the Series 1" index! 
[image]
and have actual index for the two columns or if not possible simply remove it from the chart?
I also didn't get the way that YAxis is adding Ticks to chart! Is there any way to specify the number of Ticks and Max, Min Values?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Green', 'Pink']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [{
                name: 'Point 1',
                color: '#00FF00',
                y: 500
            }, {
                name: 'Point 2',
                color: '#FF00FF',
                y: 5
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the legend by adding this object to the container (right after series)

```
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    }
```

You can set the tick interval on the yAxis like so:

```
    yAxis: {
        tickInterval: 25
    }
```

It's all documented here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

I encourage you to read it and experiment with the examples in-line.

Comment: Also, you can disable specific series in legend using `series.showInLegend = true|false` ([docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.showInLegend))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that column grafs don't support legend. If you want remove it just write under initialize

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        ....
        ....
        ....
    });
    $('.highcharts-legend').remove();
});
```

It should work. :)

Comment: You can simply disable legend, like answer by DevDude. Removing HTML elements without removing events may cause errors in JS and memory leaks.